# Error: System.JSONException: no content to map to Object due to end of input at test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, json, callout, code-coverage

I am working on a salesforce app and can't get the test class of one of my functions right. Attendee_Backup__c is a custom object that stored data retrieved from an external API. fetchAttendeeJSON() is the method used to call the API. I am using an HttpCalloutMock called AttendeeMockHttpResponseGenerator to add test data for the test class.  Every time i run the test class i get an error on Class.System.JSON.deserializeUntyped. The error seems to occur because there are no data to add in the Map but i am declaring those in the HttpCalloutMock class. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

**Error**

> System.JSONException: no content to map to Object due to end of input

**Method**

```
    public PageReference getBackupAttendees() {
    //Variable Declarations
    List<Attendee_Backup__c> lstAttendeeBackobj = new List<Attendee_Backup__c>();

    //Read Web Service

    selectedBackAttendee = fetchAttendeeJSON(requestEndpoint + 'attended');

    Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(selectedBackAttendee);
    String status = (String)data.get('status');
    Integer count = (Integer)data.get('count');
    List<Object> results = (List<Object>) data.get('results');

    for(Object result: results) {
        Attendee_Backup__c attendeeBackObj= new Attendee_Backup__c();
       Map<String, Object> res = (Map<String, Object>) result;
       attendeeBackObj.Attendee_Backup_U_Id__c= Integer.valueof(res.get('u_id'));
       attendeeBackObj.Attendee_Backup_EA_Event_Id__c= Integer.valueof(res.get('event_id'));
       attendeeBackObj.Attendee_Backup_Title__c= String.valueof(res.get('title'));
       attendeeBackObj.Attendee_Backup_Forename__c= String.valueof(res.get('forename'));
       attendeeBackObj.Attendee_Backup_Surname__c= String.valueof(res.get('surname'));
       attendeeBackObj.Attendee_Backup_Email_Address__c= String.valueof(res.get('email'));
       attendeeBackObj.Attendee_Backup_Registration__c= String.valueof(res.get('registration'));
       attendeeBackObj.Attendee_Backup_Checkin__c = String.valueof(res.get('checked_in'));
       attendeeBackObj.Attendee_Backup_Event_Group_Registered__c= String.valueof(res.get('event_group_registered'));
       attendeeBackObj.Attendee_Backup_Event_Registered__c= String.valueof(res.get('event_registered'));
       lstAttendeeBackobj.add(attendeeBackObj);

    }

    if(Attendee_Backup__c.Attendee_Backup_U_Id__c.getDescribe().isUpdateable()){
    //Update object
    upsert lstAttendeeBackobj Attendee_Backup_U_Id__c;
}
PageReference syncRend = new PageReference('/apex/DelegateManagerSync?id=' + auth.Id); //redirect to Sync page if auth key is valid 
     syncRend.setRedirect(false);
return syncRend;
}
```

**HttpCalloutMock Class**

```
@isTest
public with sharing class AttendeeMockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {
    // Implement this interface method
    public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        // Optionally, only send a mock response for a specific endpoint
        // and method.
        system.debug(req.getBody());
        system.debug(req.getMethod());
        system.debug(req.getEndpoint());


        System.assertEquals('endpoint here', req.getEndpoint());
        System.assertEquals('GET', req.getMethod());

        // Create a fake response
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setHeader('dm', 'test');
        res.setHeader('api-key', '0000000000000000000');
        res.setHeader('event-id', '1');
        res.setBody('{"status":"Success","count":4,"results":[{"delegate_type":"Default","event_attend_id":10505,"u_id":17359,"event_id":5,"registration":1,"checked_in":null,"title":"","forename":"Adele","surname":"Green","email":"adele_gray@standardlife.com","register_date":"2017-03-24 17:23:19","event_group_registered":"DM6000 Group 3","event_registered":"Salesforce Test Event","user_information":"","date_of_birth":"0000-00-00","company":"","company_role":"","phone_number":"","mobile_number":"","attendee_group":"","plus_guest":0,"guest_of":null},{"delegate_type":"Default","event_attend_id":10506,"u_id":17360,"event_id":5,"registration":1,"checked_in":null,"title":"","forename":"Kirsten","surname":"Green","email":"kirsten_lamb@standardlife.com","register_date":"2017-03-24 17:25:54","event_group_registered":"DM6000 Group 3","event_registered":"Salesforce Test Event","user_information":"","date_of_birth":"0000-00-00","company":"","company_role":"","phone_number":"","mobile_number":"","attendee_group":"","plus_guest":0,"guest_of":null},{"delegate_type":"Default","event_attend_id":10504,"u_id":13001,"event_id":5,"registration":1,"checked_in":null,"title":"","forename":"Hazel","surname":"Ritchie","email":"hazel_ritchie@standardlife.com","register_date":"2017-02-08 15:14:51","event_group_registered":"DM6000 Group 3","event_registered":"Salesforce Test Event","user_information":"","date_of_birth":"0000-00-00","company":"","company_role":"","phone_number":"","mobile_number":"","attendee_group":"","plus_guest":0,"guest_of":null},{"delegate_type":"Default","event_attend_id":10503,"u_id":15104,"event_id":5,"registration":1,"checked_in":null,"title":"","forename":"Kyri","surname":"Zinonos","email":"kyriakos@delegatemanager.com","register_date":"2017-03-15 09:50:26","event_group_registered":"DM6000 Group 3","event_registered":"Salesforce Test Event","user_information":"","date_of_birth":"0000-00-00","company":"","company_role":"","phone_number":"","mobile_number":"","attendee_group":"","plus_guest":0,"guest_of":null}]}');
        res.setStatus('OK');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
    }
}
```

**fetchAttendeeJSON method**

```
        public String fetchAttendeeJSON(String endpoint)

            {

            try        {
        List<Event__c> evEvent = [SELECT Event_Id__c,Event_Group_Id__c FROM Event__c WHERE Event_Name__c LIKE :selectedEventValue LIMIT 1];
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        request.setHeader('dm', auth.Authentication_Site__c);
        request.setHeader('api-key', auth.Authentication_Key__c);
        request.setHeader('event-id', evEvent[0].Event_Id__c);
        request.setEndPoint(endpoint);
        request.setMethod('GET');
        request.setTimeout(120000);
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        return response.getBody();

            }

            catch(Exception ex)

            {
            return '';
            }


            }
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest 
public class SyncExtensionControllerTest {

    @isTest public static void testBackupAttendees() {
       Authentication__c auth = new Authentication__c();
        auth.Authentication_Site__c ='testsite';
       auth.Authenticated_as__c='testing@testing.com';
       auth.Authentication_Key__c='00000000000000000000';
       insert auth;

       Attendee_Backup__c att = new Attendee_Backup__c();              
       att.Attendee_Backup_EA_Event_Id__c = 2;
       att.Attendee_Backup_Email_Address__c = 'test@test.com';
       att.Attendee_Backup_Event_Group_Registered__c = '1';
       att.Attendee_Backup_Event_Registered__c = 'Test Event';
       att.Attendee_Backup_Forename__c = 'TestF';
       att.Attendee_Backup_Surname__c = 'TestS';
       att.Attendee_Backup_Register_Date__c = system.today();
       att.Attendee_Backup_Title__c = 'Mr';
       att.Attendee_Backup_U_Id__c = 5;
       att.Attendee_Backup_Registration__c = '1';
       att.Attendee_Backup_Checkin__c = '';
       insert att;



      test.startTest();
      Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new AttendeeMockHttpResponseGenerator());
      PageReference pageRef = Page.DelegateManagerSite;
      Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
      ApexPages.StandardController stcontroller1 = new ApexPages.StandardController(auth);
      SyncControllerExtension a = new SyncControllerExtension(stcontroller1);
      a.getBackupAttendees();
      test.stopTest();


        }
}
```

Comment: Debug the returned response. Most likely there is an error or no response is being returned from the mock. Also post the fetchAttendeeJSON class

Comment: i ve edited the post and added fetchAttendeeJSON method as well @Eric

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want key-value pairs in your JSON, the proper object notation wraps the map in curly braces (`{}`). You missed your opening brace.

**Incorrect**

```
'..., "results": ["delegate_type": ...}]'
```

**Correct**

```
'..., "results": [{"delegate_type": ...}]'
// missing brace: ^
```

---

If I paste your current payload into [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/), I get:

> ```
> Error: Parse error on line 5:
> ... [       "delegate_type": "Default",     "even
> ----------------------^
> Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'
> ```

What this means is that you've assigned an `array` to the `"results"` key, but then tried to use `object` syntax within your square brackets (`[]`). Valid [`array`](http://www.json.org/) notation:

> An array is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with [ (left bracket) and ends with ] (right bracket). Values are separated by , (comma).
>
> [image: array]

Compare that with [`object`](http://www.json.org/) notation:

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with { (left brace) and ends with } (right brace). Each name is followed by : (colon) and the name/value pairs are separated by , (comma).
>
> [image: object]

See also: **[JSON](http://www.json.org/)**.

Comment: Where did you get them or did you create them.

Comment: @Eric Added proper linkage.

Comment: In your solution are you creating an Array of ONE Object by using [{}]? If so, why not just create an object {}

Comment: @Eric I think it's supposed to be an array of objects based on naming and existing syntax, `"results"` being plural.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. Guess I could have just scrolled up and looked at the code `List<Object>` - Nice answer, Those images are helpful....To often we rely on JSON2Apex and JSONLint without actually having a deep understanding of the reason for why things do or do not work....i.e. we get lazy, I know I have

Comment: @AdrianLarson Thanks for the useful information.My json is now valid but am still getting the same error. i validated the json with JSON Lint as well. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7):

You're missing a quotation mark:

```
    res.setBody('{"status": "Success","count": 4,"results":["delegate_type": "Default", "event_attend_id": 1295, "u_id": 1295,"event_id": 1, "registration": 1,"checked_in": 0,"title": "Mr","forename": "Albert", "surname": "Alexander", "email": "ch6ure6mdp1378wgkfbt9@delegatemanager.com", "register_date": "2017-01-26 10:20:04", "event_group_registered": "DM6000 Group 1", "event_registered": "DM6000 Large conference","user_information": "","date_of_birth": null,"company": "","company_role": "","phone_number": "","Mobile Number": "","attendee_group": "","plus_guest": 0,"guest_of": null}]}');
                                                            ^ quote missing here
```

Generally speaking, I prefer to make sure I avoid mistakes using raw strings by serializing a map:

```
res.setBody(JSON.serialize(
    new Map<String, Object> {
        'status' => 'Success',
        'count' => 4,
        'results' => new List<Object> {
            new Map<String, Object> {
                'delegate_type' => 'Default',
                'event_attendee_id' => 1295, ...
            }, ...
        }, ...
    }));
```

Or, of course, you could make some concrete classes to serialize:

```
public class CalloutResult {
    public String status;
    public Integer count;
    public DelegateItem[] results;
    ...
}
```

Comment: i do have it, it must have deleted while i was posting the question

Comment: @KyriZ. Your JSON is somehow incorrect, then. You're getting a JSON deserializing error, so your JSON is wrong.

Comment: i have corrected my json string and edited my question but still getting the same error

Comment: Simple and brilliant self-disciplining mechanism. Why didn't I think of serializing maps *face palm*.